# Python - Pandas - Insert Single Value on One Row per Date

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a column, for every 24-hours interval, the first date record should contain the max value of `df.score`.

So the new column, `daily_max_score`, should contain the `df.score.max()` just once (on the first daily record, usually at 00:00:00, but not always at that hour and minute).

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2019-04-19 23:00:00','2019-04-20 00:00:00','2019-04-20 01:00:00', '2019-04-05 08:00:00',
             '2019-07-31 23:30:00','2019-08-01 00:00:00','2019-08-01 01:00:00', '2019-08-01 02:00:00'],
    'ID': ['ID F', 'ID F', 'ID F', 'ID F',
             'ID B', 'ID B', 'ID B', 'ID B'],
    'score': ['50', '100', '99', '99',
             '75', '25', '25', '80']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

df

date    ID  score
0   2019-04-19 23:00:00 ID F    50
1   2019-04-20 00:00:00 ID F    100
2   2019-04-20 01:00:00 ID F    99
3   2019-04-05 08:00:00 ID F    99
4   2019-07-31 23:30:00 ID B    75
5   2019-08-01 00:00:00 ID B    25
6   2019-08-01 01:00:00 ID B    25
7   2019-08-01 02:00:00 ID B    80
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
date                    ID      score   daily_max_score
0   2019-04-19 23:00:00 ID F    50      50
1   2019-04-20 00:00:00 ID F    100     100
2   2019-04-20 01:00:00 ID F    99      NaN
3   2019-04-05 08:00:00 ID F    99      99
4   2019-07-31 23:30:00 ID B    75      75
5   2019-08-01 00:00:00 ID B    25      80
6   2019-08-01 01:00:00 ID B    25      NaN
7   2019-08-01 02:00:00 ID B    80      NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert your text date values into actual datetimes via `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`.

Then group on the dates via `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)`.

Get the max daily score for each date, first converting the text values to integers for the purpose of getting the max value (vs. max lex sorted value). Convert the result back to a string.

Create a dataframe of the daily max scores, using the index location of the minimum datetime for each date, i.e. `index=gb['date'].idxmin()`.

This dataframe of the indexed `daily_max_score` can now be joined to the original dataframe (which joins on index by default), producing the desired result.

Note that both the `score` and `daily_max_score` are still strings (i.e. objects), which is how they were originally assigned and thus inferred to be the desired type.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
gb = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)
max_daily_scores = gb['score'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).max()).astype(str)
daily_max_score = pd.DataFrame(
    max_daily_scores.tolist(), 
    index=gb['date'].idxmin(), 
    columns=['daily_max_score']
)

>>> df.join(daily_max_score)
                 date    ID score daily_max_score
0 2019-04-19 23:00:00  ID F    50              50
1 2019-04-20 00:00:00  ID F   100             100
2 2019-04-20 01:00:00  ID F    99             NaN
3 2019-04-05 08:00:00  ID F    99              99
4 2019-07-31 23:30:00  ID B    75              75
5 2019-08-01 00:00:00  ID B    25              80
6 2019-08-01 01:00:00  ID B    25             NaN
7 2019-08-01 02:00:00  ID B    80             NaN
```